# object not detected in a Map

Tags: java, nlp

I have this HashMap: `HashMap<NGram, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();`
I'm trying to fill it (snippet is in a loop):

```
NGram ng = new NGram(param);
if (countMap.containsKey(ng)){  // or if(countMap.get(ng) != null){
    int counter = countMap.get(ng);
    countMap.put(ng, ++counter);
}
else{
    countMap.put(ng, 1);
}
```

But `countMap.containsKey(ng)` never returns true (when it should), so the else-statement will always be executed! I overwrote `equals()` and `hashCode()` of `NGram` and they're working just fine. With primitive datatypes the snippet will work.

So, my question is: How do I convince Java, that there's already the object in the HashMap?

Here's the code of `toString()`, `hashCode()` and `equals()`:

```
public String toString(){
    String ret = "";
    for (String s : previousToken){
        ret += s + " ";
    }
    ret += token;
    return ret;
}

public boolean equals(NGram other){
    if(this.toString().equals(other.toString())){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public int hashCode(){
    String ts = this.toString();
    int result = 3;
    for(int i = 0; i < ts.length(); i++){
        result = 2 * result + ((int)ts.charAt(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code from the `equals` and the `getHashCode` methods?

Comment: Maybe you have never added any `NGram` object so you will never go into the code within the `if` ?

Comment: @KevinWallis OP did say *"snippet is in a loop"*, so it's more likely that `param` is used in `equals()` and is always unique, e.g. it is the loop variable.

Comment: @Andreas: `param` is generated in the loop, it's a string-array and from time to time the content is the same as before.

Comment: This would probably be simpler with a `MultiSet` from something like Guava.

Comment: @chrylis: can't use other APIs

Comment: @MasterBolle as hint this is not the common way to implement `equals` :D

Comment: @KevinWallis: I'know :P but it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: _When using a hash-based Collection or Map such as HashSet, LinkedHashSet, HashMap, Hashtable, or WeakHashMap, make sure that the hashCode() of the key objects that you put into the collection never changes while the object is in the collection. The bulletproof way to ensure this is to make your keys immutable, which has also other benefits._ [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: I don't know if your `toString` method does change?

Comment: @KevinWallis the hashCode() doesn't change it's return value while an object is in the Map, toString() doesn't change either

Comment: Have you already debugged? Because I implemented an example and it works without any problems

Comment: oh okay, that's the last bug I have...

Comment: It was false, I already removed it. 
How much objects are you adding into the `HashMap`? And can you make a breakpoint the `else` branch and check if it is entered

Comment: About 18 million...`else` is entered

Comment: Have you also checked if the elements you expect are contained in the `HashMap`? Because with this count of elements it is really important to have a correct `hashCode` and `equals`

Comment: Yes, there are many keys with the same `hashCode`, as expected, and the `equals()` is using the ´hashCode()` now :)

Comment: `equals()` *cannot* use `hashcode()`, since `hashcode()` doesn't generate unique values for unique objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what your 3 methods should be.
This is what is called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *(Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example)*.

The primary concept is that constructing a new combined string by calling `toString()` is not the right way to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

This is mostly for performance reasons. With [18 million objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627618#comment62737972_37627618) added to the map, performance of `equals()` and `hashCode()` matters.

Another reason it's a bad idea, is that `toString()` may not show all values of the object, or that two different objects may still have the same `toString()` result, e.g. if tokens could contain spaces, then concatenating them would not be able to differentiate `A B`, `C` from `A`, `B C`.

For the example, a `String[]` is used for the `previousToken` field, and a varargs constructor is used to simplify testing. Null tokens not allowed. Yours is likely slightly different, but this shows the concepts.

```
public class NGram {
    private String   token;
    private String[] previousToken; // could also be List<String>
    public NGram(String ... allTokens) {
        if (allTokens.length == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("At least one token is required");
        for (String s : allTokens)
            if (s == null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
        this.token = allTokens[allTokens.length - 1];
        this.previousToken = Arrays.copyOfRange(allTokens, 0, allTokens.length - 1);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : this.previousToken)
            buf.append(s).append(' ');
        return buf.append(this.token).toString();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        NGram that = (NGram) obj;
        return this.token.equals(that.token) &&
               Arrays.equals(this.previousToken, that.previousToken);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.token.hashCode() + 31 * Arrays.hashCode(this.previousToken);
    }
}
```

**TEST**

This shows a faster, more compact version of the code to add a new object to the map. It is faster because it only performs one lookup per add, and made more compact by using a ternary operator instead of an `if` statement, combining the two `put()` calls.

It's isolated in a helper method for easier testing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<NGram, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
    add(countMap, new NGram("Foo"));
    add(countMap, new NGram("Bar"));
    add(countMap, new NGram("Foo", "Bar"));
    add(countMap, new NGram("This", "is", "a", "test"));
    add(countMap, new NGram("Bar"));
    System.out.println(countMap);
}
private static void add(Map<NGram, Integer> countMap, NGram ng) {
    Integer counter = countMap.get(ng);
    countMap.put(ng, (counter != null ? counter + 1 : 1));
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{Bar=2, Foo=1, This is a test=1, Foo Bar=1}
```

As you can see, the duplicate `Bar` value is counted twice.

---

If you end up with lots of duplicate objects, i.e. with high counter values, then using an immutable `Integer` object as the counter is not great for performance. You can use an `int[1]`, but a mutable helper class is better, since it can provide a good `toString()` implementation.

```
private static void add(Map<NGram, Counter> countMap, NGram ng) {
    Counter counter = countMap.get(ng);
    if (counter == null)
        countMap.put(ng, new Counter(1));
    else
        counter.increment();
}
private static final class Counter {
    private int count;
    public Counter(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    public void increment() {
        this.count++;
    }
    public int get() {
        return this.count;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(this.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep that's working...so I'm going to go into the corner and shame my self -.-